# How to store null values to dictionary c#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I found that if my value in database is null the app would crash while I storing it to dictionary, here's my code:

```
private async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetProducts(long productId)
{
    return await _dbContext.Products
       .Where(prod => prod.productId == productId)
       .Select(prod => new
       {
           prod.ProductStockReferenceId,
           prod.ProductTitle
       })
       .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.ProductStockReferenceId, x => x.ProductTitle);
}
```

And I've realized that if `ProductStockReferenceId` in database is null the app would crash, how come and what could I do to prevent this?

Thanks

Cheers

Comment: `.Where(prod => prod.productId == productId && prod.ProductStockReferenceId != null)`?

Comment: @John that means that it would skip rows where ProductStockReferenceId is null?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Comment: `null` cannot be used as key in a dictionary, because you need a hashcode of the key. And the key must be unique. So you _could_ replace `null` with some magic value, but it still would crash if you have multiple rows where the key is `null`.

Comment: @RenéVogt thanks for info Sir ! What might be workaround to solve this? What is your suggestion? Is it possible to add values like this to `lookup`, I mean does lookup supports` null` ?

Comment: Do you need to support `null`? I'm not sure looking up using `null` as a key to a title really makes sense, unless you're trying to find all products that don't have a key set. Though if that's the case, it doesn't make sense to do it in this way.

Comment: @AluanHaddad `GroupBy` also skips `null` values

Comment: Ah right forgot

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether you want to retrieve also items with null ProductStockReferenceId you have two options. 

Filter out records with null:

```
return await _dbContext.Products
       .Where(prod => prod.productId == productId && prod.ProductStockReferenceId != null)
       .Select(prod => new
       {
           prod.ProductStockReferenceId,
           prod.ProductTitle
       })
       .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.ProductStockReferenceId, x => x.ProductTitle);
```

or you can create custom (must be unique) key and store problematic items there:

```
var nullIndex = 0;
return await _dbContext.Products
    .Where(prod => prod.productId == productId && prod.ProductStockReferenceId != null)
    .Select(prod => new
    {
        prod.ProductStockReferenceId,
        prod.ProductTitle
    })
    .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.ProductStockReferenceId ?? $"null:{nullIndex++}", x => x.ProductTitle);
```

But be sure to create custom keys that won't be present in ProductStockReferenceId so DbKeys and CustomKeys will not overlap